# How to get a-link (a href) background image in css to resize with javascript code

Tags: javascript, css, image, hyperlink, resize

I've been racking my brain trying to get two problems figured out. One is an image cropping and the other is and image resizing one.  Here is a overview of the code I have:

HTML code:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="columnDiv1">
        <!-- a div here a div there -->
    </div>
    <div class="columnDiv2">
        <div class="iconDiv1"><a href="/area1/index.html" id="iconDiv1_link">Icon 1</a></div>
        <div class="iconDiv2"><img src="/images/div2Icon.png" id="div2IconImg" width="1" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnDiv3">
        <!-- a div here a div there -->
    </div>
    <div class="bottomRowDiv">
        <!-- a div here a div there -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">

.mainDiv {
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 1112px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.columnDiv1 {
z-index: 20;
position: absolute;
width: 33.36%;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
border: 0px solid;
}

.columnDiv2 {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30.31%;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid;
}

.columnDiv3 {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    width: 36.33%;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid;
}

.bottomRowDiv {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid;
}


/* stuff in here for columnDiv1 */

.iconDiv1 {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid;
}

.iconDiv2 {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid;
}

/* stuff in here for columnDiv3 */

/* stuff in here for bottomRowDiv */

#iconDiv1_link {
    display:block;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    background: url(/images/div1.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}

#iconDiv1_link:hover {
    background-image: url(/images/div1hover.png);
}

</style>
```

JavaScript code:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('sizeImageMap()');

function sizeImageMap()
{

    // get screen information
    var currentScreenWidth =  screen.width;
    var currentScreenHeight = screen.height;

    // get images' information
        //define Image Icon Hash keys
    var imgIconHash = {};
    imgIconHash['image1_link'] = {};
      ...
      ...
    imgIconHash['iconDiv1_link'] = {};
    imgIconHash['div2IconImg'] = {};
      ...
      ...

    for (var imgLinkName in imgIconHash){
        var imgLink = document.getElementById(imgLinkName);
        if (imgLink.nodeName === "A") {

            imgLinkStyle = imgLink.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(imgLink, false);
            imgIconHash[imgLinkName]['src']=imgLinkStyle.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2').split(',')[0];

        } else if (imgLink.nodeName === "IMG") {

            imgIconHash[imgLinkName]['src']=imgLink.getAttribute('src');

        } else {
            // not A or IMG nodes
        }

        // get image width and height
        var tmpImg = new Image();
        imgIconHash[imgLinkName]['width']=tmpImg.width;
        imgIconHash[imgLinkName]['height']=tmpImg.height;
    }

    // initialize scaling factors
    var imgScale = 1;

    //set scaling factors
    if(currentScreenHeight >= /*given amount*/ ) // set scale
    {

        imgScale = 0.5676; // reset image scale

    } else {

        imgScale = 0.3784; // reset image scale

    }

   //resize images
    for (var imgLinkName in imgIconHash){
        var imgLink = document.getElementById(imgLinkName);
        if (imgLink.nodeName === "A") {

            imgLink.style.background.width = imgIconHash[imgLinkName]['width'] * imgScale + "px";
            imgLink.style.background.height = imgIconHash[imgLinkName]['height'] * imgScale + "px";

        } else if (imgLink.nodeName === "IMG") {

            imgLink.style.width = imgIconHash[imgLinkName]['width'] * imgScale + "px";
            imgLink.style.height = imgIconHash[imgLinkName]['height'] * imgScale + "px";

        }
    }
}
```

Note, this is a webpage content part in SharePoint, hence the "_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('sizeImageMap()');" to perform an operation similar to document.onload.

So, two problems I am having:

1. The image in the 'columnDiv2' of 'iconDiv1' seems to be being cropped.  It's size is 322px width and 128px height.  The left and top don't appear to be being cropped, but the bottom and right do appear, or more so, don't appear, as though they have been cropped.  I have seven other images in my code that are handled the same way, and have no problems with them, but this one appears to have the problem.  It's not noticeable on the first loaded image, but on the image that shows after a 'hover', you can see the cropping.
2. I can get the IMG's width and height, but not the a-href link's background width and height.  Any direction for this would be helpful.  Also, I am doing this so that the images can be resized.  Note the links are id's and not class's, as I was unable to find an easy way to access the existing images width and height, before loading, and then how to resize the a-href link's size after getting it.  As said, the IMG works fine, just the A doesn't want to cooperate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: OK, ignore #1, for some reason it started acting nice about it.  I also remember I was able to get the images, both IMG and A, width and height.  I'm just not having any luck resizing the A link's background.  The A link's will resize to crop the background image, but not the background image.  I've got to find out the right attributes to resize the background image.  I think that's why I really came here.  Sorry for asking perhaps the wrong questions, but the code is still what I have so far.  Thanks.

Comment: You have an error in your HTML: a missing `>` at the end of the second line. But what is your problem now exactly? "The A link's will resize to crop the background image, but not the background image." sounds a bit vague, if not contradictory.

Comment: Also, I don't have SharePoint here, so how can I test? You say the sp call does something "similar to document.onload", but can I assume that's what it does? Does the sizeImageMap function get called onload? You should make a self-contained example, that doesn't rely upon software that people may not have, for instance on JSFiddle. I tried to make one, but the `...` in the Javascript didn't really help.

Comment: I'm sorry Mr Lister,  the '...' would mean just more data added to the hash table.  As to the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(...), you may want to try a Google search.  Here is a blog about it:

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2009/06/22/javascript-pageload-add-function.aspx]

Comment: Mr Lister, how do you use this thing called JSFiddle?  I don't see anything about it here, though I have seen people adding links to their messages here on StackOverflow.  Thank You.

Comment: @MrLister, in the code CSS code, I have

#iconDiv1_link {
    ...
    background: url(/images/div1.png) no-repeat;
    ...
}

and

#iconDiv1_link:hover {
    background-image: url(/images/div1hover.png);
}

these are the images I'm trying to resize.

Comment: JSFiddle: go to http://jsfiddle.net and fill in the HTML, the Javascript and the CSS in the appropriate boxes, then click "Run". I tried that with your source, but it didn't do anything except cause Javascript errors in the console. So you may have to fiddle a bit before you can make it demonstrate the problem, and post the link of the saved fiddle here. This last bit is important, because if you have a working example of the problem that you can show to people, you'll have a much bigger change of getting an answer. It won't do to send people to blogs to learn about SharePoint.

Comment: @MrLister, I only provided the blog, as your response was a little impersonal.  I appreciate your advise and, yes, the blog does show, without someone having SharePoint, that the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(...) webpage response as though that someone used a document.onload() function.  Maybe this can help you, should you ever have a need in SharePoint for a document.onload call.  I will see what I can put together in a JSFiddle implementation.

Comment: @MrLister OK, filled out JSFiddle here:[http://jsfiddle.net/XE5Fp/25/]  I'm not sure how well it's going to do with the float:left/position:absolute with all the rest going on with the page.

Comment: @MrLister I've been trying to get background-size to work with the background images assigned by the background attribute in the css code.  I've tried giving it a calculated "width x height" size and even the "contain" value.  None of them seem to work, but I thought it might be a good try.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: @MrLister are you still there?  Thanks You for your help so far.

Comment: Is there anyone out there that can help with this?  I'm trying to switch the <a> links to just a div, but I'm not sure how well that's going to work.

Comment: Sorry, but your fiddle is a bit confusing. Many of the links in the page overlap each other; maybe it's better to simplify this to one link only. Also, the Javascript routine isn't being called at all. And if it was called, what are you trying to resize the images to? Unless I'm mistaken, it looks like you're setting them to what would be the default size of an image without a src, is that right? And it has an error: `if(currentScreenHeight >= /*given amount*/ )` which will cause the JS engine to give up and not do the rest of the script.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for that little bit about the if statement not being done right.  I had forgotten about it when I was typing in the code.  I'm actually going to try to do the image and background change with just a div in a div and having the div as an a-link.  I know you're not supposed to do a div inside an <a href> tag, but if I'm not able to resize the a-link image, then it's not going to work too well using the proper way. Also, I don't know if I mentioned this, but the client computers' browsers are still just IE8 and it's running SharePoint 2007.

Comment: They are working on converting to IE10 and SharePoint 2013, but that won't be until Fall, that isn't too far away, but they need these pretty quick.  Any other insight into trying to get this working would be helpful.  I'm going to try to get a new jsfiddle going with my new plan.

Comment: @MrLister - OK, I've simplified the whole question.  Right now, at least, I need help getting the image to show up in JSFiddle.  Here is the link to the code:  http://jsfiddle.net/5kahr/  Please let me know when you can see the whole image(s) and then we can proceed.  Thank You.

Comment: After correcting some problems with the CSS, I can see the image, and it changes into the other image on hover. So far, so good. http://jsfiddle.net/5kahr/2/ But the `overflow:hidden` on the outer div interferes with the `position:absolute` in the inner div, so I had to remove it.

Comment: Now I guess the question is how to resize the background graphic so that it is as high as the `a`, right?

Comment: @MrLister -  Thanks.  Yes, now I think we are on the same page.  I think the first little problem is trying to see the full image in the link.  Not just a little bar.  At least that's what I'm getting, a little bar that you can see part of the images in, but not the whole image.  After that we'll move to the next part. :)

Comment: @MrLister - OK, I got the image to show up by adding the following to the #col1div1_link:      width: 355px;
    height: 183px;
Now, I need to work on the resize and image change with the resize.

Comment: @MrLister - It seems to be getting a little better here at http://jsfiddle.net/J8FQg/ because I'm giving heights and widths of the original image.  Now I need to go about trying to get java script to resize the a link backgrounds to fit on a resized div, ... I think.  The other issue is getting it to work in IE8.

Comment: @MrLister -  Well, it's somewhat going here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nyv7a/ on the test area, but doesn't appear to be running any JavaScript.  Maybe I'm not doing a call right for the JSFiddle page.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Your latest fiddle now has the same problems as your earlier one, which I mentioned above: the Javascript contains `if(currentScreenHeight >= /*given amount*/ )` again, causing a JS error when the routine runs, and the stylesheet begins with `<style type="text/css">` again, which means the first style rule has an error and it gets ignored. I corrected the errors again, so please use the resulting fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nyv7a/1/ as a base to work with from now on.

Comment: So now the fiddle works (as you said, the routine didn't get called on a window resize; I corrected that too and it does now) but you still haven't answered my question, what are you trying to resize the images to?

Comment: @MrLister -- Sorry for getting back to you so late.  I think I'm going to have to try and use jQuery, even though I didn't want to have to load all of the library for it.  I guess I could try to make a custom one, but for now, I'm going to try to see what jQuery functions I will need to get it to work.  I'm having a little trouble with the jsfiddle saving updates.  I caught the error you found as well, but it didn't want to save it for me.  What am I missing on the update item?

Comment: @MrLister Oh!  I see jsfiddle adds a subdir to the URL for the code.  Then you have to relink it in here.

Comment: @MrLister - I am trying to resize the images to a percentage of the original size so that several images of different sizes don't have to be loaded per screen size, but just an initial load and then resize after it finds out the screen size.  I have that working fine.  The larger problem I have is that once I get the sceen size and resize the images, it doesn't resize the background on the hover image.